# Externalize unrestricted key strength policy files for Oracle JRE

Tags: java, aes, jsse

I am looking to externalize the unrestricted key strength policy JAR in Oracle JRE. I was able to find the solution for IBM JRE but not for Oracle JRE.

Below is the solution for IBM.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158921/externalizing-us-export-policy-jar-and-local-policy-jar-from-jre/40000513#40000513

Really appreciate help on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately what you are trying is not intended by Oracle. Looking at the code of Java 8 Oracle JCE one can see that the path is hard-coded:

```
private static void setupJurisdictionPolicies() throws Exception {
    String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
    String sep = File.separator;
    String path = javaHome + sep + "lib" + sep + "security" + sep;

    File localFile1 = new File(path, "US_export_policy.jar");
    File localFile2 = new File(path, "local_policy.jar");
    ...
```

The only way to "tweak" the location would be to temporarily modify the system property `java.home`. However this is really a hack!

```
String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
try {
    System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Path_to_unrestricted_key_strength_policy_files");
    Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity");
} finally {
    System.setProperty("java.home", javaHome);
}
```

Place the files in `C:\\Path_to_unrestricted_key_strength_policy_files\lib\security`. You also need to copy the other files that can be found in the JRE `lib\security` folder.

Note this code has to be executed as early as possible, (with no other thread running in parallel) because the policy files are loaded when the class `javax.crypto.JceSecurity` is loaded for the first time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert . So this means that we have to overwrite the default policy jar files in jre/lib/security folder in order to use unlimited key strength for encryption

Comment: See my updated answer. However keep in mind that this is a hack.